# Which compiler settings should be used to compile Pantheios in current OSX?

Tags: macos, clang, pantheios

Pantheios INSTALL.TXT says:

> Open a command shell in the appropriate directory that matches your compiler: ...

My compiler is Clang:

```
> gcc --version

Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) ...
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
```

Which of the compiler settings files in Pantheios 1.0.1-beta214 is the most appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use homebrew to install an older version of gcc (e.g., gcc-4.2) and use the matching Pantheios makefile, like this:

```
brew install gcc42
make CC=gcc-4.2
```

However, as far as I have been able to tell, Pantheios is not going to be buildable on a recently-updated system.  For example, as of today, building on OSX looks like this:

```
04:29:23 ~/src/pantheios-1.0.1-beta214/build/gcc42.unix$ make CC=gcc-4.2
Ensuring all STLSoft C source files are in UNIX format
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
make: *** [/Users/username/src/stlsoft-1.9.118/include/stlsoft/internal/dos2unix.has.been.performed] Error 1
```

I have also tried building on Windows as recently as 6 months ago and lost a good bit of time on it before giving up.

The library hasn't been updated in a very long time and the author has very little online activity since then.  I call that "abandoned software".  Building will very likely require a non-trivial amount of work on your part.  I'd highly recommend severing the dependency on `STLSoft` if you do because it also appears to be abandoned.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I liked the premise of Pantheios but after taking a quick look at the build system to understand how deep is a hole I'm about to go into to try and get this fixed, I decided to abandon the idea of using this library.